# intuition on linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

Could one think of functionals as generalising scalar product, i.e some set of functions acting on the linear space in a similar fashion? Giving similar geometric info in good cases.

Comment: Yes, they even use the notation $\langle \ell, x\rangle $ for $\ell (x) $ sometimes, to emphasize this viewpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429211/intuition-on-linear-functionals/1548893#comment2911473_1429211) by littleO:

> Yes, they even use the notation $\langle \ell, x\rangle $ for $\ell (x) $ sometimes, to emphasize this viewpoint.